# How can I add a new custom button and handler to x-editable pop up UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I want to add a new Button that deletes an editable li item from and UL element, that uses x-editable http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html library with bootstrap3, the html code is like, which is created dinamically.

```
<ul id='list'>
  <li class='editable'>Editable element 1</li>
  <li class='editable'>Editable element 2</li>
  <li class='editable'>Editable element 3</li>
</ul>
```

and the javascript that adds x-editable behavior is:

```
 $('#list .editable').editable();
```

To add button to the UI of x-editable I've done something like:

```
 $.fn.editableform.buttons  = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>' +
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-cancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>'+
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm editable-remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>';
```

this jsfiddle shows the base work http://jsfiddle.net/fGU58/1/
I tried adding common click handler to the button but apparently the library stops the event to propagate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably try the following:

```
$(document).delegate(".editable-remove",'click',function(e){ 
    $("#lista .editable-open[data-original-title]").remove();
});
```

Sometimes when you use a library and DOM elements are added using javascript the event desn't bind to the element, thats why I used delegate, you can use on instead but in this same format.

I noticed that x-editable adds a data-original-title attribute to the element being edited so I used that as a part of the selector.

Here's my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fGU58/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and explanation. It works with a minimun change, instead of using editable[data-original-title] as the selector, I'm using editable-open[data-original-title]. The editable-open class is added to the current edited li element, it's true the data-original-title is added, but it's kept if you edit any other, so if you edit one and saves it, if you edit another for removal, it removes two elements. Thanks again

Comment: And after almost 3 years this gives me a solution to my issue. Thanks guys!